# How can I plot points and generate a list of coordinates?

Tags: game-design, graphics, coordinates

Is there a program that lets me draw, a la pixel art, a map, and give me a list of coordinates and their corresponding colors? For example, I'd like to use a point and click interface to draw this

[image]

and then "export" this somehow.

Comment: The pixel positions _are_ the coordinates, aren't they?  Are you asking how to load a map from an image file?

Answer (score 2):

You can write a script or simple program by loading up the image (using PyImage or SDL or the like), loop over all pixels in the image, and print out those which are black (or any other color requested).

Something like this pseudo-code:

```
main(path, color):
 image = LoadImage(path)
 for y in 0 to image.height:
   for x in 0 to image.width:
     if image.GetPixelAt(x, y) == color:
       print x, y
```